# Preferred method to get sole key from a C# Dictionary that only has one key?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a code block that prints the data in a dictionary, and I'm trying to format the display differently based on the number of keys.

I'd like to have output like:

- If no keys are in the dictionary:

  > There's nothing in the dictionary.
- If one key is in the dictionary:

  > Entry {key} has value {value}.
- If more than one key is in the dictionary:

  > The following entries are in the dictionary:
  >
  > - {Key}: {Value}
  > - {Key}: {Value}
  > - {Key}: {Value}

Etc.

The code I have is something like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();

//code that populates the dictionary

string output;
if(dict.Count == 0)
{
   output = "There's nothing in the dictionary."
}
else if(dict.Count ==1)
{
   string only_key;
   foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
   {
      //Surely there is a better way to do this
      only_key = key;
   }
   output = "Entry " + only_key + " has value " + dict[key] + ".";
}
else
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.Append("The following entries are in the dictionary:");
   foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
   {
      sb.Append(Environment.NewLine + " * " + key + ": " + dict[key];
   }
   output = sb.ToString();
}
```

I don't like doing a foreach loop on the dictionary to get the key when I know it only has one key, but I'm not sure of a better method.

What would be a better way to do that?

Comment: var key = `dict.Keys[0]`

Comment: `var kvp = dict.Single(); output = "Entry " + kvp.Key + " has value " + kvp.Value + ".";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

`string only_key = dict.Keys.Single();`

An advantage of `Single` (besides eliminating the `foreach`) is that it will throw an exception if an object is added to the dictionary in-between the call to `dict.Count == 1` and `string only_key = dict.Keys.Single();`

Comment: If someone is adding keys to the dictionary while this is executing then the second part that iterates through the keys would blow up.

Comment: @ScottHannen - what do you mean by "the second part"?  Which code in the OPs example would blow-up?

Comment: `foreach (string key in dict.Keys)`. If something in another thread is modifying the dictionary then this will likely have issues. Items could be added or deleted during the iteration. If we're concerned about multithreading then it should be a `ConcurrentDictionary<string,string>`.

Comment: yes - there would be issues in that you'd be printing the last key found and not all of the keys.  I don't think it would blow-up (i.e. Exception thrown)? but regardless the result would not be as intended.  You'd have to use a lock around all of the posted lines of code (and whenever else the dictionary is used) to ensure that you're looking at the same dictionary throughout the if/else if/else - ConcurrentDictionary would not help with that - it would simply make it safe to modify the dictionary on multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to index the dictionary when you are traversing it. You can access both the key and value when you are traversing it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var thisItem in dict)
{
    output = $"Entry {thisItem.Key} has value {thisItem.Value}.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ's [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method to get the first (and only) key/value pair:

```
else if (dict.Count == 1)
{
  var keyValuePair = dict.First();
  output = "Entry " + keyValuePair.Key + " has value " + keyValuePair.Value + ".";
}
```

Speaking about LINQ, you could use it to replace your `else` block also:

```
else
{
  var header = "The following entries are in the dictionary:" + Environment.NewLine;
  var kvPairs = dict.Select(p => " * " + p.Key + ": " + p.Value);
  output = header + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, kvPairs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right - you don't need to loop through the dictionary keys if it only has one item.

If you know there's only one item then you can do this:

```
dict.Values.First()
```

or

```
dict.Values.Single()
```

The difference is that `Single` throws an exception if there's not exactly one item. Another answer suggested using this in case something gets added to the dictionary right after you checked that the count == 1. I disagree. If this is something multithreaded where another process could be modifying the dictionary then the next part where you iterate through the keys in the dictionary would also be at risk for the same reason. But unless you know that you're doing something multithreaded you don't need to worry about that. (And if it was you would use `ConcurrentDictionary<string,string>`.)

A good pattern to follow when handling a collection is to handle any number of items (1 or more) the same way. If you're creating a list of items from the dictionary and there's only one item, then create a list of one item. Something like

Your dictionary has (1) items:
Key: abc Value: xyz

Then you could choose to handle it differently if there are no items.